# Parsing Json response value Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to call one API where I need to extract the "'Invoice_URL__c" value using python script from the Json body responses as below

```py
{
  'totalSize': 1,
  'done': True,
  'records': [
    {
      'attributes': {
        'type': 'Invoice__c',
        'url': '/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Invoice__c/a031Y00000eTwQSQA0'
      },
      'Invoice_URL__c': 'https://app.Xchange.net/stream/File/InvoiceAttachment/a78a76c0-a56d-4546-ac2a-b7b5a3933fe4',
      'Payment_Record_ID__c': 'a0N1Y00003CBTTW'
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Comment: What data type does the json body have? e.g. string or dictionary

Comment: That's JSON? `json.loads` should convert it to python for you.

Comment: Based on the single quotes instead of double quotes and `True` instead of `true` we can _assume_ it has already been parsed. However, a well formed question would not force us to assume anything. Please read [ask] and see how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(response['records'])):
 print(response['records'][i]['Invoice_URL__c'])
```

This can help you get the invoice urls from json data

Comment: This assumes there there is something called "response" that has already been converted from JSON to python. OP hasn't given us enough information to know that. In this example, instead of indexing through `i`, `for record in response['recoreds'])` may be a better start.